# helm toJson function orders list alphabetically

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, to-json

I have defined an object with a few attributes in my `values.yaml` file:

```
serverOptions:
    defaultUrl:
        p1: abc
        p2: def
    cpu_request:
        p1: abc
        p2: def
    mem_request:
        p1: abc
        p2: def
```

I am saving these data to a `server_options` json file in `configmap.yaml` using this code:

```
data:
    server_options.json: |
        {{ toJson .Values.serverOptions }}
```

It works but the initial "list" of attributes gets alphabetically ordered. This is the file's content

> {"cpu_request":{"p1":"abc","p2":"def"},"defaultUrl":{"p1":"abc","p2":"def"},"mem_request":{"p1":"abc","p2":"def"}}

Is there a way to keep the original ordering?

Answer (score 1):

Json dictionaries aren't ordered, so no that's not possible. They may be alphabetically ordered when printed but that's only for readability.

Comment: Theoretically, one should not count on ordering when working with Json dictionaries, but I was curious about this specific implementation. I guess the ordering here is not for readability purposes but for other technical reasons.